# Concatenative language interpreter in Java

Tags: java, interpreter, embedding, concatenative-language

I'm interested in finding a [concatenative language](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Concatenative_programming_language) interpreter in Java. Ideally, it should satisfy the following conditions:

- It has an interpreter, not (only) a bytecode compiler for JVM.
- The language itself has decent documentation, not only a few examples and a "I'll document the rest someday" notice.
- The project is not completely abandoned.

In short, I'm looking for a reasonably "alive" concatenative language that can be embedded into Java easily.

Comment: What is a concatenative language?

Comment: I'm curious... why "an interpreter, not (only) a bytecode compiler"... what is the benefit of "interpreter" ? why a bytecode compiler should not be an "interpreter" ?.... why something like groovy isn't ok for you ? Sorry for all these questions to answer your question :-(

Comment: @Cem Catikkas: In a concatenative language, you program by composing functions which operate on a single structure (most commonly a stack), as opposed to applying functions to arguments. Examples of concatenative languages: Forth, Factor, Joy. More information can be found at: http://concatenative.org/

Comment: @Istao: The piece of software I'm trying to write will receive data at runtime which tells it how to build a certain structure. This building process can be easily described in a concatenative language. My idea is to transform the input data into the words of a concatenative language and then interpret them. An interpreter is would allow me to: 1) process the data as a stream, instead of waiting to receive all and then compile it, and 2) avoid execution of arbitrary concatenative code more easily (no need to sanitize input if I just impose severe limits on what the interpreter can do/access)

Answer (score 2):

I was looking for something similar today and ran into [JKat](http://slarba.kapsi.fi/jkat/doc/).

Answer (score 1):

I found [JOLIE](http://www.jolie-lang.org/). It says:

> JOLIE is a service-oriented programming language, that you can use to build powerful orchestrators.
>   An orchestrator is a software application that composes other services in order to obtain new functionalities.
>   Writing an orchestrator means to deal with the composition of service communications

Answer (score 1):

7th is developed as a java script engine named `"7th"`. There are [examples](https://7th-stone.com/index.php?id=11) how to interact between 7th and the calling Java™ program. Write `Engine engine = Engine.create();` in Your Java program. Execute Your 7th program by sending it to the engine in the way: `engine.eval(`*˂Your 7th program here˃*`)`.